# Hybrid app hybernated when opened via push notification

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, capacitor

I've got my iOS angular/capacitor app which is able to receive and manage push notification via capacitor event:

```
// Method called when tapping on a notification
PushNotifications.addListener('pushNotificationActionPerformed',
  async (action: ActionPerformed) => {
      await this.router.navigateByUrl('url/to/go')
      console.log('logic done);
  }
);
```

What happen from the tap is absolutely singular: **logs confirm my actions are done, but in my app nothing happens UNTIL I tap any part of the UI**. Then the route correctly update to destination.
Tested in iPhone 6 iOS 12.5

How can this be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by my own: for some reason ? cannot explain I need to wrap the router statement inside ngZone service:

this.ngZone.run(() => this.router.navigateByUrl(path));

If someone can explain these I'll appreciate :)